# асинхронность в питоне не работает

Tags: python, async-await, asyncio

У меня есть код на питоне в котором я пытаюсь использовать асинхронность, но она не работает.
Вот код:

```
import asyncio
import socket


class App:
    def __init__(self):
        class Sets:
            class Internet:
                ip = '192.168.0.129'
                port = 1337
        self.server_address = (Sets.Internet.ip, Sets.Internet.port)
        self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server_socket.bind(self.server_address)
        self.server_socket.listen(1)
        print("ожидание подключения...", end=' ')
        self.connection, client_address = self.server_socket.accept()
        self.connect_to_client()
        print("подключен")
        self.Sets = Sets
    
    def connect_to_client(self):
        self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server_socket.bind(self.server_address)
        self.server_socket.listen(1)
    
    async def start(self):
        event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        await asyncio.gather(self.server(), self.game())
    
    @staticmethod
    async def game():
        while True:
            print(f"тик")
            
    async def server(self):
        while True:
            try:
                while True:
                    try:
                        data = self.connection.recv(1024)
                    except OSError:
                        print("подключение разорвано, ожидание переподключения... ", end='')
                        self.connection, client_address = self.server_socket.accept()
                        print("подключен")
                        continue
                    if data:
                        print("#2#Received request:", data.decode())
                        ...
            finally:
                self.connection.close()
```

И основной файл:

```
from app import App, asyncio


def main() -> None:
    app_instance = App()
    asyncio.run(app_instance.start())
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Вот код с помощью которого я отправляю запросы (если вдруг надо)

```
import socket

host_address = '192.168.0.129', 1337

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(host_address)

while True:
    data = input('>>> ')
    if not data:
        continue
    client_socket.sendall(data.encode())
```

проблема в том что должна запускаться еще и функция game, которая по факту не запускается.

Comment: В показанном здесь коде нет асинхронности — и функция server, и функция game не содержат никакого асинхронного кода и полностью блокируют текущий поток

Comment: Да и функция `__init__` зачем-то тоже блокирует текущий поток, а в ней уж тем более даже намёков на асинхронность нету

Comment: а как сделать чтобы они не блокировали? мне нужны 2 одновременно работающих цикла @andreymal

Comment: @Neanod asyncio protocol server  например почитай

Comment: Ответы к этому вопросу посмотрите, возможно что-то поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48506460/4752653